Can HtmlWebpackPlugin use only the bundles in the [name] folder?
I have a webpack.config.js that scans a config folder to build different bundles in different output folders so that each of those output folders can be a standalone website. For each of those output folders, I want to inject the folder's contenthash'd bundle into src/template.html to yield an index.html written to each output folder.
The official webpack docs recommend HtmlWebpackPlugin when one wants to use an html template, but when I try (using v5.6.0 of the plugin)...
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename:  '[name]index.html'
        ,template:  './src/template.html'
    })
]

...it injects all the bundles from all my output folders into each index.html.
I have looked through the github page of the plugin, and the source of its index.js, but I cannot find a way to limit each index.html's bundle to just the one in the same output folder.
I can't use the chunks property unless it can take a value like [contenthash].js
The documentation mentions only fully-specified values, not placeholders.

you can try to use modern html-bundler-webpack-plugin.
Using this plugin you can define SCSS and JS/TS source files directly in each HTML template file.
The plugin resolves source files of styles, scripts, images, fonts, etc. in templates and replaces them in the generated HTML with output filenames.
For example,./src/template.html:
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- relative path to SCSS source file -->
    <link href="../scss/style.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- relative path to JS source file -->
    <script src="../app/main.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- relative path to image source file -->
    <img src="./picture.png" />
  </body>
</html>

The generated HTML contains URLs of the output filenames:
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.05e4dd86.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/main.f4b855d8.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <img src="img/picture.58b43bd8.png" />
  </body>
</html>

Webpack config:
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: [
        {
          import: 'src/template.html', // template file
          filename: 'index.html', // => dist/index.html
        },
      ],
      js: {
        // JS output filename
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // CSS output filename
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|png|jp?g|webp|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'img/[name].[hash:8][ext][query]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

